# TypeError: string indices must be integers when I try and get values from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Im trying to get  specific values from this data,

```
data = {'Memory': [{'SensorType': 'Load', 'Value': 51.9246254}], 'CPU Core #2': [{'SensorType': 'Temperature', 'Value': 63}, {'SensorType': 'Load', 'Value': 66.40625}, {'SensorType': 'Clock', 'Value': 2700.006}]}
```

Im trying to get the `SensorType` from `Memory` by using,

```
print(data["Memory"]["SensorType"])
```

However I get this error,

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any Ideas about why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of key `Memory` of `data` is a `list` (of one element: a `dict`), not a `dict`. So, you need to get the only element of the `list` as well:

```
data["Memory"][0]["SensorType"]
```

---

Just to note, for your example, you should get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

not the one you've posted. I presume the error message is just wrongly put.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! However, what should I do if I wanted to call for a different element of a list with multiple elements?

Comment: Sry. I normally do that. like I said its been a long day. lol

Comment: @gman1230321 No problem. Upvoted the question . Have a good break :)